# Cordova Android App AJAX Request Not Working

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

My Android App used to work well (Cordova) but suddenly fail to work with jQuery AJAX and giving a status code '0', I have already installed whitelist plugin,but still it persist.

I have both these codes in config.xml

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.3" />
```

Earlier, I had this

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Tried both access origin="*" and allow-navigation href="*" , but no use.

I have comment 'Content-Security-Policy' Meta Tag, still ajax request fails.

Cordova Version: 6.3.1

AJAX Code Example:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: 'http://' + ip + '/Home/LogIn',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { Email: email, Password: password, LogIn: true, DeviceID: client_device, OS: OS_Version },
                success: function (data) {
.......
```

Comment: try to test it with alert.. 
`beforeSend: function() {
                       alert("AJAX IN CALL");
                    },`

Comment: access origin is all you need, it allow all type of links

Comment: @proofzy beforeSend works but still return '0' ;). forgot to mention this issue started to occur after renewing the domain which i use to connect via ajax

Comment: @proofzy It failed when i tried with a test url from this site https://reqres.in/, so it confirms that there is no problem with the domain. anything to do with content security meta tag ? ( i tried with and without meta tag)                                                                                  My Tag: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />